# More efficient way of hiding/unhiding four items based on selection

Tags: jquery

Currently I hide/unhide certain select drop downs based on the users choice. To do this I have had to repeat a lot of code. I can not see a simpler way to do this but I can not help but feel that this is very bloated for it's needs.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/40/

```
$('#NumOfchildren').change(function () {
    var numOfChildren = $(this).val();
    if (numOfChildren == 0 || numOfChildren == 'child5plus') {
        $("#child1").hide();
        $('select[name="child1"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#child2").hide();
        $('select[name="child2"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#child3").hide();
        $('select[name="child3"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#child4").hide();
        $('select[name="child4"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        if (numOfChildren != 'child5plus') {
            $("#child5plus").hide();
        } else {
            $("#child5plus").show();
        }
    }
    if (numOfChildren > 0) {
        $("#child1").show();
        $("#child2").hide();
        $('select[name="child2"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#child3").hide();
        $('select[name="child3"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#child4").hide();
        $('select[name="child4"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#child5plus").hide();
    }
    if (numOfChildren > 1) {
        $("#child1").show();
        $("#child2").show();
        $("#child3").hide();
        $('select[name="child3"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#child4").hide();
        $('select[name="child4"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#child5plus").hide();
    }
    if (numOfChildren > 2) {
        $("#child1").show();
        $("#child2").show();
        $("#child3").show();
        $("#child4").hide();
        $('select[name="child4"]>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#child5plus").hide();
    }
    if (numOfChildren > 3) {
        $("#child1").show();
        $("#child2").show();
        $("#child3").show();
        $("#child4").show();
        $("#child5plus").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Create your own utility functions for common blocks of code and use selectors that capture more than one object for carrying out the same operation on multiple objects.  You are correct that one should never copy this much code this many times.

Comment: Have a look at http://knockoutjs.com/. That's an efficient way of doing what you want...

Comment: Adding to what @jfriend00 is saying, use classes to group the relevant elements together, so that you can more simply call your show / hide.  Additionally, it seems you could *hide all* before your if block, then only show the relevant ones based on your if/then statements.

Comment: Agreed with the advice of @jfriend00. You should indeed utilize functions for repetitive code like this. In addition, if you do have to use `if` statements (which occasionally you will), look into utilizing the `else if` and `else` statements as well. Several of the code blocks do the same operations as previous code blocks which is definitely an inefficient use of `if` statements.

Comment: @ifriend00 I have to hide and unhide elements on a one by one basis, so i don't follow how group classes would play a part in this example. Could you give an example using the fiddle provided please?

Comment: I don't think classes is what is required here. It is a tricky question, hence why it has no answers yet other questions asked since, have been answered. I think you will need to use a loop to loop through the elements hiding appropriate ID's based on value of select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my try at it:

```
$('#NumOfchildren').change(function () {
    var numOfChildren = $(this).val();
    $(".child-age").hide().find('select option:first').prop('selected', true);
    if (numOfChildren === 'child5plus') {
        $("#child5plus").show();
    } else if (numOfChildren) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= numOfChildren; i++) {
            $("#child" + i).show();
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csicky/LstNS/55/

Comment: Genius! why haven't you got 100K reputation!? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @TheApptracker. I have corrected a little bug. Now it selects correctly the first option of all `select` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a shoot trying to minimize the code duplication. Bascialy I added an attribute for each child number (on the div tag in which there is a select box where user enter the age of the child). It is then used to evaluate what elements to display:

```
// Display child age select boxes matching users child amount
$('.child-age').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr("data-childs") <= numOfChildren;
}).show();

// Hide others and reset any age user has entered
$('.child-age').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr("data-childs") > numOfChildren;
}).hide().find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
```

Full JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/51/

Comment: Thanks, but the fiddle is exactly the same link as the one i provided

Comment: I updated the post with - a hopefully - more useful JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

The first block can be dramatically simplified like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/LstNS/49

```
if (numOfChildren == 0 || numOfChildren == 'child5plus') {
    $('.child-age').hide().find('select > option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);

    if (numOfChildren == 'child5plus') {
        $("#child5plus").show();
    }
}
```

The other blocks could be refactored similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of eliminating duplicate functionality with a loop and then extracting it into a separate function. This is a good starting point for you to work off of. I believe all you need to do to finish this up is to set the 'selected' property.

http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/40/

```
$('#NumOfchildren').change(function () {
    var numOfChildren = $(this).val();

    if (numOfChildren == 'child5plus') {
        $("#child5plus").show();    
    } else {
        showNumSelects(numOfChildren);
    }
});

var showNumSelects = function(numChildren){
    $('.child-age').hide();
    for(i = 0; i <= numChildren; i++){
        elemName = "#child" + i;
        $(elemName).show();
    }
}
```